# Elegantly replace multiple tokens in a URL / NSString

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsstring

When I am communicating with my backend I often have URL like this:

```
http://myserver.com/api/endpoint?param1={PARAM1}&param2={PARAM2}
```

So before issuing a request I need to substitute those params with actual values. So code fragments like the following are all over my code:

```
myString = [[[uriString  stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"{PARAM1}" withString:@"..."]
              stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"{PARAM2}" withString:@"..."]
             stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"{PARAMn}" withString:@"..."];
```

I am now looking for an elegant way to substitute those params and I can think of a few options:

1. Make a category of NSString:

   ```
   [myString replaceOccurencesOfStrings:@"{PARAM1}",@"{PARAM2}",nil withStrings @"value1",@"value2",nil];
   ```
2. Make a Util which works the same as the above example, only that I pass it the string
3. Same approach as `1.` and `2.` but using a NSDictionary with key value like this: `'PARAM1' -> 'value1' ...`

What is the most efficient and elegant way to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why replace tokens if you can just use the format, for example using [stringByAppendingFormat](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAppendingFormat%3a).

The interface for the function would be:

```
-(NSString*) createRequestToURL:(NSString*) url_string withParams:(NSDictionary*) params {
//TODO:
}
```

Where key in the dictionary is param name.

Comment: I like to have URLS with named parameters, so that I can substitute them without having to look at the order of the parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `[NSString stringWithFormat]`:

```
myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myserver.com/api/endpoint?param1=%@&param2=%@", @"valueOfParam1", @"valueOfParam2"];
```

Comment: This is not a bad idea but I like to have a name for the parameters, so that the order does not matter or can change.

Answer (score 2):

I had once a project where I added a category to `NSString` which does something like this:

```
@implementation NSString (Interpolate)

#define COPYREGION(_endp)                                               \
    do                                                                  \
    {                                                                   \
        NSUInteger _pointer = _endp;                                    \
        NSRange _range = NSMakeRange(lastPoint, _pointer - lastPoint);  \
        NSString* _region = [self substringWithRange: _range];          \
        [buffer appendString: _region];                                 \
    }                                                                   \
    while (0)

- (void) appendTo: (NSMutableString*) buffer byInterpolating: (NSDictionary*) variables
{
    NSUInteger length = [self length];
    NSUInteger p = 0;
    NSUInteger lastPoint = 0;

    while (p < length)
    {
        unichar ch = [self characterAtIndex: p];
        if (ch != '$') ++p;
        else
        {
            COPYREGION(p);
            NSUInteger start = ++p;
            while (p < length && [self characterAtIndex: p] != '$') ++p;

            if (p == length) NSLog(@"Warning: missing closing '$' in substitution marker");
            if (p == start + 1) [buffer appendString: @"$"];
            else
            {
                NSRange range = NSMakeRange(start, p - start);
                NSString* name = [self substringWithRange: range];
                NSString* value = [variables objectForKey: name];
                if (value) [buffer appendString: value];
            }
            lastPoint = ++p;
        }
    }

    COPYREGION(length);
}

- (NSString*) stringByInterpolating: (NSDictionary*) variables
{
    NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];
    NSMutableString* buffer = [NSMutableString string];

    [self appendTo: buffer byInterpolating: variables];

    NSString* answer = [buffer copy];
    [pool release];
    return [answer autorelease];
}

@end
```

The syntax for substitution variables is `$name$`. An occurrence of `$$` becomes a single dollar character. Usage would be:

```
NSDictionary* subst = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"param1", @"p1", @"param2", @"p2", nil];
return [@"Some template param1=$p1$, param2=$p1$" stringByInterpolating: subst];
```